# How to display 2 alert dialogs in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display two alert boxes one from the other depending from a condition but i didn't get a solution, here is my code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder B = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final AlertDialog dialogue = B.create();
B.setTitle("Welcome !");
B.setMessage("Please enter a number :");
// Set an EditText view to get user input
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
B.setView(input);
B.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    if(input.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
    {
      dialogue.dismiss();

      final AlertDialog.Builder Be = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      Be.setTitle("Error !");
      Be.setMessage("Please enter a valid number !");
      Be.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          inal AlertDialog dialogue2 = Be.create();
          dialogue2.dismiss();
          dialogue.show();}
      });
    }
    else
       {//Do some stuff}
    });
B.show();
}
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem? We won't debug your code.

Comment: the problem is when i don't write anything in the edit box and click on OK i got a NullPointerException and not the second dialog box

Answer (score 0):

**this** in the constructor of your second Dialog referes to the previous Dialog context, change it and use the activity one.

PS: I would change that and look for a different approach, a dialog inside a dialog it's a bit messy. Check out .setError for EditTexts http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError

Comment: It worked i displayed the second dialog box but how can i re-display the first dialog box when i click on the Ok of the second one?

Comment: by not calling dialogue.dismiss();